# Getting raw request body in controller

Tags: magento2, controllers

I've been battling this issue for a bit now and it's driving me crazy.

Essentially I'm trying to get the raw posted data sent to my controller (which extends `\Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action`).

In Magento 1.x you can fetch the raw request body in a controller by running the following in a controller method:

```
$data = $this->getRequest()->getRawBody();
```

Now that I'm trying to port a M1 module to M2 I've been unable to figure out the correct way to do this.

I've tried the following (and poked at a few other things to no avail):

```
$rawBody = $this->_rawBody;
$postValueData = $this->_request->getPostValue();
$postData = $this->_request->getPost();
$getData = $this->_request->getParams();

$this->logger->debug('$rawBody:');
$this->logger->debug(print_r($rawBody, true));
$this->logger->debug('$postValueData:');
$this->logger->debug(print_r($postValueData, true));
$this->logger->debug('$postData:');
$this->logger->debug(print_r($postData, true));
$this->logger->debug('$getData:');
$this->logger->debug(print_r($getData, true));
```

The output I get in my log file from this is the following:

```
[2018-06-15 07:09:03] main.DEBUG: $rawBody: [] []
[2018-06-15 07:09:03] main.DEBUG:  [] []
[2018-06-15 07:09:03] main.DEBUG: $postValueData: [] []
[2018-06-15 07:09:03] main.DEBUG: Array
(
)
 [] []
[2018-06-15 07:09:03] main.DEBUG: $postData: [] []
[2018-06-15 07:09:03] main.DEBUG: Zend\Stdlib\Parameters Object
(
    [storage:ArrayObject:private] => Array
        (
        )

)
 [] []
[2018-06-15 07:09:03] main.DEBUG: $getData: [] []
[2018-06-15 07:09:03] main.DEBUG: Array
(
)
 [] []
```

As you can see, not a lot of data there.

The way I'm testing this is by running the following from the command line:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST --data '{"orderReference": 000000001}' http://127.0.0.1:8080/my/controller/
```

I feel like I'm missing something obvious here...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

if you want to get Body, please use the below function

```
$this->getRequest()->getContent()
```

Answer (score -2):

You have to try with response object

```
$this->getResponse()->getRawBody()
```

Comment: `PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor::getRawBody()`
Also, I'm trying to get the data sent to Magento, not the data the controller is sending out.

Comment: where you have tried? means in which class?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. I have a controller and in its `execute` method I'm trying to fetch the raw request data (in this example `{"orderReference": 000000001}`).

Comment: aah, you have tied at controller

Comment: Can you please share your magento1 code?

Comment: The M1 code to do what I want to do in a controller is just `$data = $this->getRequest()->getRawBody();`.